# Freehand plugin behaviour

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins

I've installed the QGIS [Freehand plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/freehandEditing/).

When drawing a polygon, **QGIS automatically closes the polygon when the pen leaves the graphic tablet** :

- Is there any way to turn this feature off, or at least be able pause it?
  When drawing large intricate polygons your hand can often become tired at a chance for a breather would be welcomed!
- Is there anyway to delete nodes as you go along in case you make a mistake?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: For additionnal info regarding the maintenance of this tool (and the people doing the maintenance if you have any feature request) : http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Freehand-editing-td5042615.html

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `Add Feature` tool [image] instead of [Freehand Editing Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/freehandEditing/) when drawing a polygon. The `Add Feature` tool in QGIS main tools can let you draw a polygon without being closed automatically unless you did a right-click on the mouse to finish the sketch.

If you want to delete a node you can click on Node tool [image] which allows you to select any node and then delete.